# jQuery + Rails: variable selector doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I am trying to record the score of a specific route after the user clicks on a star.

```
$('.ratings_stars').on('click', function() {
        var score=$(this).attr("data-score");
        var route_id=$(this).attr("data-route_id");
  });
```

It does record the score, but it either selects only "1" or "0" for the route or leaves it empty.

[image: Scores]

I have tried the following:

```
var route_id=1; // displays "1" as to be expected
var route_id='#'; // displays "0"
var route_id=$(this).attr("data-route_id"); // no link to any route
var route_id=$(this).attr("route_id"); // no link to any route
```

Can anyone see what I don't see?

Edit: I have posted the whole code here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45AEY/1)

Many thanks.

**The solution:** `var route_id=$(this).parent().attr("id").replace('Route', '');`

Comment: I'm not getting what is the problem. Can you be more specific? This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BFqWB/ works as expected. What is different from you case?

Comment: @acdcjunior Many thanks for your answer and trying. The issue is that the data is written back to views/scores/index.html.erb, but the route_id is not picked up correctly. I have added a screenshot to the main post. I just cannot figure out what I am missing. I have looked at other examples here, but what works there doesn't work for me. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried getting attributes this way: var route_id = $(this).data("route_id") ? Have you included jquery script?

Comment: @Ron, the image is good, but if you cold provide the HTML of the ***Listing Scores*** page, it'd be easier to help (if possible, the full HTML).

Comment: @AntonGrigoryev, yes, I did and tried again, but it leaves the route empty.

Comment: @acdcjunior, I have added a link to jsfiddle.net/45AEY/ as the whole html might be a bit to much for this page. Unfortunately it doesn't pick up the stars.

Comment: @Ron, in the fiddle you posted, there are `data-score` attributes, but there aren't any `data-route_id` attributes. If they don't exist, you can't get their value.

Comment: @acdcjunior; I have them in the HTML file `<div class="star_1 ratings_stars" data-score="1"></div>`. I am pretty new to it so it is possible that it doesn't work, but it works somehow to record the score. I "just" need to link it to the chosen route.

Comment: @Ron, there, I took a guess. See if that's what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/45AEY/:

```
<h3 class="bar">Beginners</h3>
<div class="content">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#/routes/1">Route 1</a>
        <div id="Route1" class="rate_widget">
        <div class="star_1 ratings_stars" data-score="1">1</div>
        <div class="star_2 ratings_stars" data-score="2">2</div>
        <div class="star_3 ratings_stars" data-score="3">33</div>
        <div class="star_4 ratings_stars" data-score="4">44</div>
        <div class="star_5 ratings_stars" data-score="5">55</div>
        </div>  
        <div class="total_votes">vote data</div>        
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As there are no `data-route_id` attributes, I believe the `route_id` you are trying to catch is the number of the `Route` of the parent `div` (in the example above, the parent `div` is `<div id="Route1" class="rate_widget">`.

In that case, this line

```
var route_id = $(this).attr("data-route_id");
```

Can be switched to this line:

```
var route_id = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace('Route','');
```

And `route_id` will have the ID of the route. (In the example above it'll be `1`).

Give it a go: http://jsfiddle.net/2B9GM/

<sup>**Ps.: In your original fiddle, you did not set jQuery as library. Make sure you have it set in your fiddles and, more importantly, imported (through the `script` tag) in your HTML page.**</sup>

Comment: May I use the chance and ask if you know any easy to understand guide/tutorial on how to display the sum and average of the rating back to the homepage into the "total_votes"? I only found some guides using php, but I don't use it.
I've already asked that question here, but no one seems to know the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380139/how-to-display-a-score-summary-in-rails-using-jquery-and-display-it-back-to-the

Comment: I used this tutorial, but this php doesn't work for me.
[link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/building-a-5-star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php/)